# Where are the tesla's Parenthetical statements?

Tags: financial-statements

Open the url in browser:

https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459021004599/tsla-10k_20201231.htm

Click `Sections` button on the left upper side,it shows that there are 8 statement on the webpage:

[image]

But I can only find 5 statements on the webpage:

```
Consolidated Balance Sheets
Consolidated Statements of Operations
Consolidated Statements of Comprehensive Income (Loss)
Consolidated Statements of Redeemable Noncontrolling Interest and Stockholders' Equity
Consolidated Statements of Cash Flows
```

All the following `Parenthetical statements` can't be found.

```
Consolidated Balance Sheets (Parenthetical)
Consolidated Statements of Operations (Parenthetical)
Consolidated Statements of Redeemable Noncontrolling Interest and Stockholders' Equity (Parenthetical)
```

Where are the tesla's Parenthetical statement then ?

And i check apple's annual financial reports in sec website:

https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019321000105/aapl-20210925.htm

It says that there are 6 statements :
[image]

```
Financial Statements   6
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF COMPREHENSIVE INCOME
CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEETS
CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEETS (Parenthetical)
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF SHAREHOLDERS' EQUITY
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF CASH FLOWS
```

I find out only 5 ,where is the `CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEETS (Parenthetical)`?

```
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF COMPREHENSIVE INCOME
CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEETS
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF SHAREHOLDERS' EQUITY
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF CASH FLOWS
```

Do the financial statements ending with (Parenthetical) exist?If it do exist ,why can't find in the webpage above,where are they?If it don't exist,why the number labeled in the webpage (for tesla it is 8 ,for apple it is 6) is larger than real number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Parenthetical)` just means the footnotes of the statements (e.g. those marked with `(1)`). It's not a separate statement.